# Python/Windows doesn't let numpy allocate RAM "numpy.core._exceptions.MemoryError"

Tags: python, numpy, ram

I know this question was already asked, but this is special:
I am using Windows and I am trying to allocate a 250000*200 Array (via numpy.random.normal) out of float64 variables. Those add up to 50000000 float64 variables, which (when they each take 4 Byte) need 200.000.000 Bytes, which are approx. 190 MB.

I have 8GB RAM and always AT LEAST 2 GB RAM free and I still get the same error. AND I actually allocated 10GB RAM from my SSD, that means that I should have at least 12GB RAM free.

Using Windows 10 64bit

Comment: Can you also share the relevant parts of your code? And welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: found a solution. Thanks though :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working! I had the 32 Bit Version of Python (I should be ashamed of me :D) and now I installed the 64 bit version and it works fine.

THANKS for everyone who had liked to help me though!